# Middle value as pivot in quicksort

Tags: python, python-3.x, quicksort

I am tasked at school to write up quicksort algorithm with the middle value as the pivot, not middle element. So for example in a list [5,9,6,7,8] the pivot should be 7 as that is the middle value, and not 6 which is at the middle index. I would greatly appreciate any help of figuring this out, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your attempt and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: do you mean `sum([5,9,6,7,8]) / len([5,9,6,7,8])`

Comment: Almost, when tested with even amount of elements it gives a fraction which I guess can be solved with //, but when I tested that with a list like [21,95,63,45,17] it gives 48.2 or 48 which is not an element in the list, so cannot be used as a pivot

Comment: Many quicksort implementations rely on finding elements == pivot to prevent from scanning beyond the boundaries of a sub-array. If the code is not using an actual value form an element in the array, the code will need to be changed to do boundary checks.

Comment: The pivot doesn't have to be present in the list.  As long as the value is in the range represented by the list. If there are an even number of elements in the list how do you choose which is the middle value, without using a value that isn't in the list?

Comment: @rcgldr - Most collections I've seen automatically use their own boundary checks when one is iterating through them.

Comment: @tinstaafl - Visual Studio C++ std::sort() doesn't have any boundary checks in a release build, only in a debug build.

Comment: @tinstaafl: When there's an even number of items in the list all implementations that I've seen pick the left one (the one where `index % 2 == 0`.

Comment: @MohitPancha: The pivot value does not need to be present in the list for QuickSort to function - you just need to make sure your logic doesn't exclude any elements when making the recursive calls following the current partitioning step.